# python-compare two dataframes and write the missing values of df 2 if other values in that row are identical

Tags: python, dataframe

I recently encountered a problem where I have dataframe 1 (contains complete data) and dataframe 2 (contains most data similar to df1 except for one column), I am trying to compare these two dfs and write the missing value of df2 from df 1 if other values in that row are identical

please see below for an example:

df1
column1, column2, column3
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5

df2
column1, column2
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
5, 6

what I want to get as output:
df3
column1, column2, column3
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5
4, 5
5, 6

Thank you very much for anyone trying to help!

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share some code and explain exactly where you're stuck, or what you expected to work but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration will stop when shortest frame ends.
You cannot create a frame with empty cells that is why I filled cells without data with nan. It is very easy to work with nan for future manipulations. Hope it helps.

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4], 'col3':[3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':[2,3,4,5,6]})


df2['col3'] = np.nan
for (_, a), (_, b) in zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()):
    if a['col1'] == b['col1'] and a['col2'] == b['col2']:
        df2.iloc[_, 2] = a['col3']

print(df2)
```

'''

### OUTPUT

'''

```
 col1  col2  col3
0     1     2   3.0
1     2     3   4.0
2     3     4   5.0
3     4     5   NaN
4     5     6   NaN
```

'''